# How do I log the country's name whenever it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS, [REST API](https://mledoze.github.io/countries/), axios to get the list of countries and display them in cards on the page. I need to make a history list of the last 5 countries clicked but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Logging all the countries on the page works but I need to log the specific country that is clicked.

[Here's the code for the component](https://pastebin.com/VL1q8Yqw)

```
<strong class="card-text" v-on:click="handleClick">{{
          country.name
        }}</strong>
```

```
        handleClick() {
      //console.log("[response]", JSON.stringify(this.countries));
    },
```

Comment: You can try using the filter function of JavaScript to filter the current country you selected from the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to know how to pass information about which country was clicked to `handleClick`?

Something like this maybe?

```
<strong class="card-text" v-on:click="handleClick(country)">
    {{ country.name }}
</strong>

handleClick(country) {
    console.log("Clicked on: " + country.name);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a array to save the clicked country data

```
<strong class="card-text" v-for="country in counties" @click="handleClick(country)">
    {{ country.name }}
</strong>

handleClick(country) {
    this.array.push(country)
    this.array.slice(0, 5)
},
```